# use sed to replace version number in a package.json file

Tags: json, sed

This is a part of my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "org-team-module",
    "version": "1.1.0-snapshot",
    "description": "Some description",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run build && npm run copy-static-assets && npm run serve",
        "build": "rimraf dist && npx tsc && echo npm run lint",
```

I want to replace the version with a particular value, say 1.2.0-snapshot

This is what i have till now;

```
sed -nE -i 's/(^\s*"version": ")(.*?)(",$)/\11.2.0-snapshot\3/p' test.json
```

However when I add the -i flag to replace; the entire file gets replaced with the searched value.
i.e. the entire file contents after replace is

```
        "version": "1.2.0-snapshot",
```

How can i just replace that particular line in the file

Comment: I would suggest to simply change the arguments to `-E -i` and remove the `/p`, e.g. `sed -E -i 's/(^\s*"version": ")(.*?)(",$)/\11.2.0-snapshot\3/' test.json`

Comment: `sed` is not appropriate to work with JSON files; your script will fail if `"version"` and its value are not on the same line (not a common situation but definitely valid JSON). I suggest to use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead. It knows how to parse and generate JSONs and the script becomes smaller and more clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`sed` is not appropriate to work with JSON files; your script will fail if `"version"` and its value are not on the same line (not a common situation but definitely valid JSON).

I suggest to use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead. It knows how to parse and generate JSONs and the script becomes smaller and more clear.

Replacing the value of `version` with a fixed value is as simple as:

```sh
jq '.version="1.2.0-snapshot"' package.json
```

It does not modify the original file but dumps the modified JSON on screen. Your script can redirect its output to a temporary file then move the temporary file over the original file, like this:

```sh
jq '.version="1.2.0-snapshot"' package.json > /tmp/package.json
mv /tmp/package.json package.json
```